# AJAX Call to python view from JavaScript not happening (Django)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-views

#### Views.py (View function)

```
@csrf_exempt
def updateLogs(request):
    print("Log AJAX call")
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

#### javascript file

```
function updateConsoleLogOnPage(var1){
    jobName = var1.value;
    alert(jobName);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "my-logfetch",
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}', text: jobName },
        success: function callback(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

URLs.py

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url('my-ajax-test/', views.updateSUTInfo, name='ajax-test-view'),
    url('my-logfetch/', views.updateLogs, name='my-logfetch-view'),
]
```

## Calling Javascript function from HTML onchange event of SELECT.